# Factory Girl - Why are Records being continually created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to factory girl. What I'm trying to do is create 2 users, which belong to a group, joined by the permission model. Here's what I have. When I run this one rspec, it creates more than 2 users, 4+. Why? thanks

**factories.rb:**

```
require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:fname) { |n| "fname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:lname) { |n| "lname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@google.com" }
  f.password               "password"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  f.invitation_code        "xxxxxxxx"
end

Factory.define :group do |f|
  f.association :user
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "myGroup#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:private_email) { |n| "myGroup#{n}" }
end

Factory.define :permission do |f|
  f.role_id         1
  f.user {|i| i.association(:user)}
  f.group {|i| i.association(:group)}  
  f.creator_id {|i| i.association(:user).id}
end
```

**incoming_mails_controller_spec.rb:**

```
describe IncomingMailsController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before do
    @user = Factory.create(:user, :permissions => [Factory.create(:permission)])
    @user2 = Factory.create(:user, :permissions => [Factory.create(:permission)])  
    @group = Factory(:group)
  end


  it "should create a new IncomingMail record in the db" do
  ....
  end
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Factory.create(:user...) creates 1 one user (you have two of these, so thats two users right there). And creating two new Factory.create(:permissions) also creates a user by the rules you set up in your define(your associations), thus equaling 4.

If you wanted to to only create two users here, you could do

```
@user = Factory.create(:user)
@user1 = Factory.create(:user)
@perm1 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user)
@perm2 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user1)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried that, but it was missing the group so I updated your code to:     @user = Factory.create(:user)
    @user1 = Factory.create(:user)
    @group = Factory(:group)
    @perm1 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user)
    @perm2 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user1)
 that still is creating 7 users.

Comment: Because the group association is creating a user, and the permissions association is creating a user(under the creator_id method). And since the permission is also defining a group which in turn also creates another user by the association. I didn't add the entire code of what you need to do, however after this comment I think you get the point :)

Comment: Mike, I get the problem I don't get how to fix it or where I can find an example showing how to solve for this scenario. I appreciate your help but could really use more than pointing out the problem. What I've noticed with StackOverflow is that as soon as one person answers then others are less likely to do so, so if you're able to help please do others maybe someone else can?

Comment: @AnApprentice: edit the question and add the new code you wrote -- that will raise the question's visibility.