# Alternatives to factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In my opinion and for my purposes, `factory_girl` completely sucks. Some limitations include:

#### No debugging support

If I include `debugger` statements, they are treated as model attributes. Instead of invoking the debugger, I just get strange errors.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :admin do
    name do
      debugger # <-- Does not work.
      Forgery(:name).full_name
    end

    email                 { Forgery(:email).address }

    debugger # <-- Does not work either.

    password              "secret"
  end
end
```

#### Limitations to associations

Am I too stupid or is there no elegant way to add two posts to a user?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title "Foobar"
    content "Some content"
  end


  factory :user do
    name { Forgery(:name).full_name }
    email                 { Forgery(:email).address }

    # This does not work, if the Post model requires Post#user to be set.
    posts [FactoryGirl.create(:post), FactoryGirl.create(:post)]
  end
end
```

See also [Factory Girl - Why are Records being continually created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370266/factory-girl-why-are-records-being-continually-created)

#### Tends to trigger strange bugs in rails

I can't remeber what happend, but often strange problems arise with factory_girl.

So given these examples. Are there any alternatives to factory_girl that do not have these issues?

Comment: Why would you debug the creation of a mockup?

Comment: Does the first debugger statement not go into the debugger?  I would expect it to.

Comment: Have you asked here or on the factory_girl mailing list how you could achieve any of the things you outlined above? We've helped people with all these issues before. Quick answers: try `Kernel.debugger` instead of just `debugger`, and try using an `after_build` callback to add the posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A debugger statement in a DSL can be problematic.  You don't know when it will run.

FactoryGirl could run the DSL, save a representation of the factory, and use the internal representation in memory when the factory is used.

Also, there is no variable to inspect except self.  The self is going to be a germ object to build the definition.

At the risk of answers all being defense of FactoryGirl, if your alternatives to FactoryGirl are DSLs to populate data, you are still going to have the problem of debugging support.

Alternatives include fixtures and just calling ActiveRecord to populate test data.  Really FactoryGirl doesn't have much over ActiveRecord, it's just more symbol oriented calls, so people get to make meaningful symbol names which is all FactoryGirl was supposed to do.

You cannot put a debugger statement in the middle of a fixture, or in the middle of a hash that you are sending to a create method, but at least you won't be tempted to.

(The See also Factory Girl - Why are Records being continually created?, was an example where FactoryGirl was working perfectly, but the user told it to create four records, and then was surprised when it created four records.)

So maybe if you stick with fixtures and ActiveRecord calls things will be dumbed down enough that you won't get confused.

Comment: In your defense, sometimes factory girl gets complicated, and there is reason to wonder what it is doing and in what order, so one could be tempted to step through it with the debugger.

factory :sdmstore_complex_project do
  deployment_type             { FactoryGirl.create(:sdmstore_deployment_type) }
  technical_overview          { |prj| prj.deployment_type.technical_overviews.create }
end

Answer (score 5):

I agree and found Factory Girl overly complicated for what it does.

I wrote a simpler gem a while ago which (at the time at least) was a drop in replacement for Factory Girl-based tests.

The factory definitions use much simpler Ruby and therefore behave as you would expect them to.

Check it out:
https://github.com/ginty/cranky

Answer (score 2):

Why are you debugging inside the factory definition instead of in your code on the resulting objects?

And what's wrong with

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
2.times do
  FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user)
end
```